# EDITED: How to insert NAs between specific character values in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-management

I have a list of values with a dummy character, "break", coded in to signal the line breaks:

```
 [11] "break"       "-9.737715"   "0.000091"   "-0.000340"   "-0.001318"
 [16] "-38.103233"  "-10.327046"  "break"      "27.469583"   "break"
```

I need to: 1) count the characters in between each occurrence of "break", and 2) insert NAs into the strings that do not meet the specified character count (= 9). As an example, my ideal output from the code above would be:

```
         [11] "break"       "-9.737715"   "0.000091"   "-0.000340"   "-0.001318"
         [16] "-38.103233"  "-10.327046"  "NA"         "NA"          "NA"
         [21] "break"       "27.469583"   "NA"         "NA"          "NA"   
         [26] "NA"          "NA"          "NA"         "NA"          "NA"
         [31]  "break"
```

Can't find the solution anywhere...help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `nchar`? `x[x != "break" & nchar(x) != 9] = NA` should do it.

Comment: I think you should show your intended output on a small and reproducible example to make it clear what you want. E.g. if you had `x <- c(1,2,3,"break",1,2,3,4,"break",1)` what would be the end result?

Comment: the `-` is being included in the character count? or you're trying to identify when the number is between 10 and 100?

Comment: are you trying to count the number of characters in each string of number, or the number of entries between each "break"?

Comment: Trying to count the number of entries between each "break" and add NAs where that count falls below 9.

Comment: Edited to show my intended output.

Comment: Gregor- your code turns all values to NAs, and doesn't change the length of the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```r
y <- c()
cnt_betwn_break <- 0

for(i in 1:length(a)){
  ifelse(a[i]=='break',
         {if(!(cnt_betwn_break %in% c(0,9))) y <- c(y, rep(NA, 9 - cnt_betwn_break))
          cnt_betwn_break <- 0},
         cnt_betwn_break <- cnt_betwn_break + 1)
  y <- c(y, a[i])
}
y
# [1] "break"      "-9.737715"  "0.000091"   "-0.000340"  "-0.001318"  "-38.103233" "-10.327046" NA          
# [9] NA           NA           "break"      "27.469583"  NA           NA           NA           NA          
#[17] NA           NA           NA           NA           "break"
```

**Sample data:**

```
a <- c("break", "-9.737715", "0.000091", "-0.000340", "-0.001318", "-38.103233", "-10.327046", "break", "27.469583", "break")
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much, Prem. Just tried this out and works like a charm, as shown above.

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is *almost* what you are asking - it adds a group of NA's after the last break.  (If you know the last entry is a break, then you can remove it before counting the breaks. If the last entry is not a break, it should work.)

```
x <-  c("break" ,"-9.737715", "0.000091", "-0.000340", "-0.001318", "-38.103233",  "-10.327046",  "break" , "27.469583",   "break")
count_breaks = cumsum(x == "break")
unlist(tapply(x, count_breaks, function(.x) {
  c(.x, rep(NA, 10 - length(.x)))
}))
```